# administer/give a test

Tags: meaning, difference

1. The teacher **gave** a test.
2. The teacher **administered** a test.

What is the difference between #1 and #2?

> Administer : to give **officially** or as part of a ritual (From Merriam
>   Webster)

I think #2 implies that this is a standardized test which involves official procedures. #1 could be any test.   Am I correct?

Comment: The first implies that the teacher gave an informal test of their own devising. The second says the teacher was supervising a test set by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, "administer" can be used for any kind of test.  However, since it sounds particularly *formal*, it is generally used only for standardized tests, usually ones that the teacher did not write.

So, yes, you are correct.  Note also that anyone can "administer" a test.  This person is called a ["proctor"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proctor), which can also be used as a verb.

> Miss Henrings will be **proctoring** the final exam.